# Previous attributes propagated on subsequent calls

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsattributedstring

I've encountered a weird scenario, where the previous attributes (which is a custom attribute for attributed string) generated by my extension method was also assigned on succeeding calls. It behaves like a static value was cached and assigned it wherever I invoked it.

```
extension Model {
    func attributedString() -> NSAttributedString {

        // Generate an icon, represented by the type of model
        let icon = ...

        // Merge both icon and the value of the ziptag
        let preferredAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: icon.attributedString())
        let attributedValue = NSAttributedString(string: self.value)
        preferredAttributedString.append(attributedValue)

        // Mention Attribute
        let mentionAttributeKey = NSAttributedStringKey(HKWMentionAttributeName)
        guard let mentionAttribute = HKWMentionsAttribute.mention(withText: self.value, identifier: self.id) else {
            fatalError("mentionAttribute can't be nil")
        }
        mentionAttribute.metadata = self.entityMetadata()

        // Color Attribute
        let foregroundColor = UIColor.blue

        // Set the attributes
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [mentionAttributeKey : mentionAttribute,
                                                     NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : foregroundColor]

        preferredAttributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range: preferredAttributedString.range)

        return preferredAttributedString
    }
}
```

This is how I replicate it. Lets say I do have two objects of type model that have an extension method declared and implemented above.

```
let modelA = Model()
let modelB = Model()
let attributedStringA = modelA.attributedString()
let attributedStringB = modelB.attributedString()
```

I've logged both attributed strings above and I am expecting it would present `modelA` and `modelB` attributes respectively, but instead it produces only `modelA` on both attributed strings

To add more data on the problem. The icon generated above was a custom font [FontAwesome](https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit) which will also produce an attributed string and be prepended on the `Model`'s attributed string (using the system's font).

I've run **Xcode's lldb** on the statements that produces the needed attributes and it's reporting right; but once I assigned the attributes on the attributed string the said problem start appearing

Comment: Extension?  Create a class.

Comment: Yes, that's an extension for the `Model` class. Did you mean to create a class that accepts `Model` and produces an attributedString?

Comment: Maybe `HKWMentionsAttribute.mention` and `self.entityMetadata()` is returning static data.. or `Model` has static data or the same values.. we don't know, but there's no issue in the above snippet. So far, I can see you allocated the same models via the same constructor with no different data..

Comment: Both `HKWMentionsAttribute` and `Model` doesn't have any `static` implementation [HKWMentionsAttribute.h Declaration](https://github.com/linkedin/Hakawai/blob/master/Hakawai/Mentions/HKWMentionsAttribute.h) [HKWMentionsAttribute.m Implementation](https://github.com/linkedin/Hakawai/blob/master/Hakawai/Mentions/HKWMentionsAttribute.m)

Comment: @Brandon I've removed the implementation of the extension and created two class that consumes the Model. `ClassA` produces the attributed string and the `ClassB` produces the icon needed for the attributed string. I've let the Xcode's debugger (LLDB) run through the statements and it is producing the right attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding an unused custom attribute on the snippet on my question

```
// Mention Attribute
let mentionAttributeKey = NSAttributedKey(HKWMentionAttributeName)
let mentionAttribute = ....

// Foreground Color
let foregroundColor = UIColor.blue

// Trash Attribute
let trashAttributeKey = NSAttributedKey("TrashAttribute")
let trashAttribute = Trash()
```

After adding the trash attribute, it now works perfectly; Because there's no more lingering attributes made by this extension method previously specifically on the **Icon** part of the Attributed String